# Auto Resize Dynamic Text Font as3

Tags: actionscript-3, text, dynamic, resize, autosize

I have dynamic text field that must be a fixed width and height.

The actual text that will populate the dynamic text field is a variable.

What I would like to do is to reduce the font size if the text does not completely display within the text field's dimensions.

Any ideas on how I can accurately perform this?

Also, I am using AS 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give this a try if you're still looking: (this assumes your TextField is set to "multiline" and is only 1 line high when it inits)

```
var smallLimit:int = 10;
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

tf.text = "THIS IS WAY TOO LONG";

var testSize:int = 200;
while( testSize > smallLimit ){

    updateFormat( testSize );
    //trace( tf.numLines  );

    if( tf.numLines > 1 ){
        testSize--;
    }else{
        testSize = smallLimit;
    }
}

function updateFormat(size:int):void{
    format.size = size;
    tf.setTextFormat( format );
}
```

Comment: It works!. Thanks NHubben and everyone else. One little problem though. It resizes text to fit only on one line. Is there anyway to move excess text to a next line before resizing. i.e fit textfield width and height. Many thanks

Comment: Instead of checking number of lines, you could set up a target width and height and check each one. If width is cool, but height is not.. make it smaller and check again. It's worth spending some time and getting handy with TextFormat and TextField manipulations. Cheers

Comment: someone else just posted this snippet to a new post asking the same question:  http://icodesnip.com/snippet/actionscript-3/scale-text-to-fit-in-textfield-scale-textfield-to-fit-text

Comment: Many many thanks guys. That link was really helpful NHubben. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var tfspecial:int = tfFontSize + tfInterLine;

while (tf.numLines < tf.height * tfspecial) {
    tf.height += tfspecial;
}
```

Comment: hey 2smacks, thanks for the answer. But pls forgive my lack of knowledge. I'm new to this and you have just spoken a strange language. lol, I don't know how I can implement that code. pls expand.

Comment: Something weird happened with "...numLines<tf..." so I adjusted the spacing and formatting and cleaned it up a bit so the whole thing will display.

Comment: tf is your textField.
What don't you understand ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function but i dont know why it works only once on dynamic text. When replace content on tf it nocorectly sets tfHeight. but it works if you set constant tfHeight value insted var tfHeight = tf.height;

```
function fitFontSize(tf:TextField){
    //pobieramy oktualna wysokosc pola tekstowego
    var tfHeight = tf.height;
    // ustawiamy automatyczne rozszerzanie sie pola ze wzgledu na zawartosc
    tf.autoSize =  TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT ;
    // tworzymy obiekt tekst format
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    //ustawiamy poczatkowa wielkosc fonta na 100
    var tfFontSize:Number =100;
    // przypisujemy do obiektu
    myFormat.size = tfFontSize;
    tf.setTextFormat(myFormat);
    /*Z PETLI FOR POMNIEJSZAMY SUKCESYWNIE CZCIONKE O JEDEN
PIKSEL DO MOMENTU GDY tf TEKSTOWE OSIAGNIE POŻADANĄ 
WYSOKOSC LUB MNIEJSZA*/

    for (var i:int = 0; i<100; i++){
        tfFontSize-=1;
        myFormat.size = tfFontSize;
        tf.setTextFormat(myFormat);
        if (tf.height<= tfHeight){
        break;
        }
    }
}
```